# How to handle "Change Reason" in a PUT Request?

Tags: web-services, rest

I work with a system that requires that each change be audited and a reason specified for each change.  In trying to keep with good REST design, we want to use the HTTP verbs correctly.

With regards to this particular case, I am unsure about best way to handle this situation.  Lets say we have a simple entity:

```
URL:  /users/100
JSON: { username: 'usr1', firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' }
```

Now if I want to update the username from 'usr1' to 'user1', our system requires that I specify the reason for the change.

Without the change reason requirement, we could easily just PUT the JSON to the URL.

My question is what is the best way to send the change reason to the server.  Here are the options I have come up with so far:

- Add a changeReason attribute to the entity.
- Add changeReason as a query parameter.
- Add a changeReason header.

None of these options seem right to me.  Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some thoughts to your proposed solutions:

- Add `changeReason` to the `JSON` object: Is bad, because (if using the same `mime-type`) the `GET` would not need that field.
- As query parameter: Is wrong, because it is not a parameter for the resource (but for the request)
- As header: Is wrong, because this is an out-of-band information.

So, certainly this information should be part of the request representation, and the update happens on the user, so the URL should not change (it is the same resource). I propose the [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) method, which was created seemingly for the exact purpose you describe.

With the `PATCH` method, you have to describe a "change" representation, that specifically describes a change you want applied to a resource. This document format will be different from any resource formats, and could then contain a "changeReason". Looks something like this:

```
PATCH /users/100
Content-Type: application/vnd.company.auditedchange+json

{
   "replaceFields": {
      "username": "user1"
   }
   "changeReason": "Typo in username."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I knew my options weren't right and I like this method.  What are your thoughts on how to do the patch?  This article (http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) describes it in a more generic way.  Is the structure of the PATCH request important?

Comment: I agree with that article that the `PATCH` is often misused. The structure of the `PATCH` is important, as the specification demands a dedicated `mime-type` for it. (Unless you don't care of course) The proposed `RFC 6902` format does however not allow for additional information as far as I can see. Also, it is json-document-change specific a bit for my taste. You can write your own representation as long as it describes changes in somewhat generic way.

Comment: So after going down this road a little bit, one of the things missing from my original question was that each individual changes requires a change reason.  Does it seem like the correct approach to use a model for the patch that has: [{ op: 'replace', path: 'email', value: 'js@gmail.com', changeReason: 'typo in address' }]?

Comment: Sure, that works. The only (debatable) constraint is, that it should be independent of the resource representation you modify (which it is in your case). It should be theoretically possible to modify other resources with the same format.

Comment: Ok, well now I have to deal with the delete.  We need a change reason on the delete.  Should I somehow use the patch verb for that, or is it acceptable to send that in the body to the delete?

Comment: Yes, the `DELETE` can have a body. It's not used that often, but it's possible. I would prefer that to `PATCH`.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a new resource `userchange`. `POST` to it with the information about the change.

```
POST /userchange
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": 100,
  "changes": {
    "username": "user1"
  },
  "reason": "fixed name"
}
```

The server would execute the change on the user and log the reason.